# Factor functions into multiplicative factors

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have a function $f(x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 ,x_4).$ We know that we can factor it int two ways as $f(x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 ,x_4)=\phi_1 (x_1 ,x_2 )\phi_2(x_3 ,x_4 )=\psi_1 (x_1,x_3)\psi_2(x_2,x_4)$

Show that we can completely factor the function as: $f(x_1 ,x_2 ,x_3 ,x_4)=\varphi_1(x_1)\varphi_2(x_2)\varphi_3(x_3)\varphi_4(x_4)$.

I'm sure this is true. This is just something I think of but cannot prove rigorously.

Comment: Or please point me to previous study on this problem. I'm clueless

Comment: I add a solution, but please let me know if I did right. Most importantly, is there a study of this sort of different partition of factorization?

Comment: I think this is somehow linked to bipartite graph or something. Please comment if you know where general theory would be available.

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=\phi_1 (x_1 ,x_2 )/\psi_2(x_2,x_4) =\psi_1 (x_1,x_3)/\phi_2(x_3 ,x_4)$. LHS is a function of $x_1, x_2,x_4$. RHS is a function of $x_1, x_3,x_4$. So g is constant for all $x_3$ and $x_2$. That is, g is a function of $x_1,x_4$.

Then we have two equations:
$$\phi_1 (x_1 ,x_2 )=g(x_1,x_4 )\psi_2(x_2,x_4) $$
$$\psi_1 (x_1,x_3)=g(x_1,x_4 )\phi_2(x_3 ,x_4) $$

The first equation gives us a decomposition $$\phi_1 (x_1 ,x_2 )=g(x_1,x_4=c )\psi_2(x_2,x_4=c):=r_1(x_1)r_2(x_2)$$

Similarly
$$\psi_1 (x_1,x_3)=g(x_1,x_4=c )\phi_2(x_3 ,x_4=c)=r_1(x_1)r_3 (x_3) $$

So we have
$$f=r_1(x_1)r_2(x_2)\phi_2(x_3,x_4)=r_1(x_1)r_3 (x_3) \psi_2(x_2,x_4)$$.

What follows is trivial.